# Laravel many to many filter

Tags: laravel, search, filter, many-to-many

In a many to many relationship it is pretty straitforward to find all the elements belonging to the one element. But I cannot figure out how to filter multiple. Let me explain.
Let's say we have a standard Post and Tag models. They are in many to many relationship. To find all tags of a post we would do:

```
Post::find(1)->tags()->get();
```

and to get all post for some tag we would do

```
Tag::find(1)->posts()->get();
```

What I cannot figure is search for all posts containing exactly 2, 3 and etc. tags. For example, how to find all posts with tags 'it' and 'smartphone' but not the post which have only 'it' or only 'smartphone'.

I tried whereHas but it will return and OR'ed posts like 'it' || 'smartphone'. What I am looking for is AND'ing like 'it' && 'smartphone'.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the `has()` method.

For example, to find a post which only has 2 tags as well as eager load the tags, do the following...

```
Post::with('tags')->has('tags', '=', 2)->get()
```

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_has

If you need to find all tags of a certain name for a certain post, you'd use `whereHas()`

For example, if you need a post which has the tags for 'it' and 'smartphone', you can do the following...

```
$tags = ['it', 'smartphone'];

Post::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags) {
    $q->whereIn('name', $tags);
})->get();
```

You can also pass in additional parameters to the `whereHas` function so if you want only posts which have only the tags you are looking for and no additional tags, you'd do the following...

```
$tags = ['it', 'smartphone'];

Post::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags) {
    $q->whereIn('name', $tags);
}, '=', count($tags))->get();
```

This assumes your pivot table is well managed though.  If you have defaults (one post has the same tag multiple times), this will not work.  I'd suggest having a composite primary key on the pivot table which includes the 2 foreign keys.

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas